# SEO for same site in multi locations

Tags: seo, geotagging, geotargetting

I have a portfolio website I want to market in both Australia and also in the UK. I have purchased the domains but now want to make sure that Google will not penalize me for having duplicate content

Can someone please advise me the best practice/s to make sure that both sites optimise good for SEO in these regions

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow and is too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your concerns are well-answered at the heart of Google itself. Take a look at [this link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en) (go to the bottom of the page):

> Websites that provide content for different regions and in different languages sometimes create content that is the same or similar but available on different URLs. This is generally not a problem as long as the content is for different users in different countries.